# call a code behind method from J Query Button Click event instead of ASP Button click event

Tags: jquery-ui

i want to access code behind when I clicked on a J Query Button , like when i Clicked on a ASP Button . there are some code for this purpose like this .

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit.aspx/yourmethodname",
    data: "{yourmethodparam:" + somevar + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
error: function(err, response) {
    alert("error");
}
});
```

But for this code we have to use static method ... and in static method i can't access object's like Textbox1.text and so on... 
i want when i clicked on a jquery button it worked exactly like a asp Button .
and i want the jquery button be in Update Panel to avoid of refreshing page
i'm very pleased if anyone can help me ...

Comment: http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Add a Text Box and a Button in your .aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="myButtonClick" runat="server"  OnClick="myButtonClick_Click"Text=" "  />
```

Step 2) write your desired code behind function for the click event

```
public void myButtonClick_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string svar = TextBox1.Text;
    Alert.Show(svar);
}
```

Step 3) Call button click event from jquery at your ajax success message

```
               success: function (response) {

                    $("[id$='_myButtonClick']").trigger('click');

                },
```

With this you can accomplish jquery ajax requirement(if any) as well as code behind button click event requirement too.

Enjoy Sharpening the C.
Cheers.